# mysql updating cell content issue

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to update a value in my database but am recieving the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' ('new_user') VALUES ('1') WHERE 'id'= 5' at line 1
```

I am trying to UPDATE the table 'users' in the column 'new_user' where the id is equal to $userid. But it don't work. Please help.

```
$newuservalue = '1';

$notnewuser ="UPDATE 'users' ('new_user') VALUES ('$newuservalue') WHERE 'id'= $userid ";

 $query2 = mysql_query($notnewuser) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Are you using a scripting language? PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your syntax is wrong.
It should be:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2 [WHERE Clause]
```

So, remove the "values" part of your query and put in the "set" part.

[Here's a link to the official documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

i have that problems some times, that's the code to insert a new row :d

It should be:

```
UPDATE users SET new_user='$newuservalue' WHERE id=$userid
```

you also don't need to put quotes around your column names, that might give some problems as well.